# When True or False depends

Tags: probability, logic

How do we decide when a statement's truth value depends in True/False question?

In my experience, when it is in a True/False question, then the answer is False.
For example,

**If $P(A)=0$, then $A =\emptyset$.**

However, I choose False because (1) In general it is False and (2) the reasoning/implication is False since $P(A)=0$ does not necessarily imply $A =\emptyset$.

If we just leave the reasoning aside, only consider it as a statement. We know $P(A)=0$, it does not tell anything about the element in $A$. The set $A$ might contain some elements that have 0 probability, $A$ might indeed is empty. So it is like just asking you $A$ is empty or not without any helpful information. In such a case, do we say this statement is False?

An simple example can be:

**If $x \in R $, then $x>0$.**

Hence, **if the statement in general is False but might be true in some case (i.e. depends), do we say it is False?**

The problem arises when we say it is false while the negation is also False: **$x \in R $ and $x \le 0$.** So is it better to say it depends?

Comment: What does it mean "a statement's truth value depends" ??? In a given "context" a statement has a truth value: "now in my town it does not rain"; this is a fact. "Now I'm weraing a red shirt" is false, and so on.

Comment: We can consider [three-valued logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/) to mangae "vague" situation. See also [Vagueness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "depends" means in the given "context", we cannot decide the truth value, and I provided 2 examples for it.

Comment: The answer below answer it; the truth-value of: "if $x \in \mathbb R$, then $x > 0$" depends on the value assigned to $x$ (in the domain $\mathbb R$). If we assign to $x$ the value $1$ the resulting "interpreted" formula is true, while with $0$ assigned to $x$ the formula is false.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA (1) Thx for answering the question you asked in the comment, "What does it mean "a statement's truth value depends" ??? ". (2) And even better, that is what I am thinking, some statements cannot be decided to be true or false because it depends.

Answer (score 1):

The "technical" term in logic is: *satisfaction* (to be *true* in an interpretation).

A sentence like $\forall x \ (x \ge 0)$ is satisfied in an interpretation with domain the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers; in symbols:

> $\mathbb N \vDash \forall x \ (x \ge 0)$.

The same formula is not satisfied in an interpretation with domain the set $\mathbb R$ of *real* numbers; in symbols:

> $\mathbb R \nvDash \forall x \ (x \ge 0)$.

---

In a specific interpretation $\mathcal I$, if a sentence $\sigma$ is true, then its negation $\lnot \sigma$ is false (see [Law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle)).

Things are different for "open" formulas, like $x > 0$; in this case we need a way to assign a "meaning" to the variable $x$ in a specific context.

If we consider an interpretation with domain $\mathbb N$ and we assign to $x$ as "temporary meaning" (there is a "technical" way to do this in logic, through *variable assignment* functions) the number $1$, we have that the formula $(x > 0)$ is satisfied: $\mathbb N \vDash (x > 0)[x \leftarrow 1]$.

If instead we assign to $x$ the value $0$, the formula is not satisfied.

Thus, in conclusion, the truth value in a given interpretation of a formula with a free variable, like $(x > 0)$, depends on the value assigned to $x$.

Comment: I am sorry that you misinterpret my question. You answer is totally correct, but I am asking how to decide T/F when a statement can be true/false in the given context, ie: depends. However, since it is a T/F question, we can only answer T or F. In the 2nd example, it is False, but the negation is also False.

Comment: @tautology - No; without a value assigned to $x$ the formula $x > 0$ is neither true nor false. A free variable in a math formula is like a pronoun in natural language: the phrase "it is red" has no defined meaning (or truth value) if we do not define what is the reference of "it".

Answer (score 1):

I'll venture a wild guess: you're talking about "True/False" questions that some math instructors (myself included) like to ask on tests. There are several different situations that can appear on such a question.

1. The question is very concrete, without any free variables. That's an easy case: "$2\times2=4$" is clearly *True*, while "$2\times2=5$" is clearly *False*.
2. The question does contain some free variables in it, just like in both examples you provided. Two things about such questions: first of all, there's usually some context that's assumed to be clear both to the teacher and to the student; and second, they are silently, by default, assumed to be **general "for all"** kinds of statements, i.e. whether it is **always** true.

Turning to your examples.

(1) By asking whether

> If $P(A)=0$, then $A=\emptyset$

is True or False, your instructor actually means to ask (roughly speaking) whether

> For any set $A$, if $P(A)=0$, then $A=\emptyset$

is True or False. Since, as you correctly explained, this is not always true, the correct answer is *False*.

(2) Similarly, by asking whether

> If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x>0$

is True or False, your instructor actually means to ask (roughly speaking) whether

> For any $x$, if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x>0$

is True or False. Again, this is *False* because some real numbers are not positive (even though some are).

Short summary: the usual interpretation of such questions is that:

1. *True* means **ALWAYS True**;
2. while anything else, i.e. **it depends because sometimes it's true and sometimes it's false**, is treated as *False*.

---

Sorry for such a long answer, but I should also address two misconceptions in your post.

(1) The answer is **not** always *False*. For example:

> If $\det A\neq0$, then $A$ has an inverse matrix.

I intentionally made it sloppy, but that's how it often is. On the one hand, we should specify that $A$ is a square matrix so that the question is meaningful. On the other hand, the very fact of using "$\det A$" assumes that $A$ is a square matrix. Mathematically, we can get very nitpicky about this. But in the reality of college math tests, these statements are pretty much always meaningful; the only question is whether they are true or false.

(2) The negation of "If $A$, then $B$" is **NOT** "If $A$, then not $B$". So your reasoning in the last paragraph of your post is wrong. There's nothing wrong with both "if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x>0$" and "if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x\le0$" being *False* because they are **NOT** negations of each other.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it for your example "det A". Seems like it is true anyway. Like what you said, when we applied det for A, A must be a square matrix. There is no ambiguity. And Thanks for pointing it out for the negation, I meant to say "A and not B", already changed it in the question

Comment: And to be clear, when people phrases "if $x \in R$", doesn't they refer to "Let $x \in R$" or simply "$x \in R$"? It just states what is x. So in this very example, if we are sloppy, we can say the negation is "if $x \in R$, then $x \le 0$", which is interpreted as "Let $x \in R, x \le 0$"

Comment: @tautology: You can interpret the original statement like that... but you can **NOT** negate it like that. As Mauro ALLEGRANZA already explained, a statement like "$x>0$" does **NOT** have a truth value because $x$ is undefined in it. In fact, it's not even a statement -- it's a proposition with a variable $x$.

Comment: @tautology: The actual original statement is not "$x>0$", nor even "If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x>0$" -- they both are propositions (with a variable $x$), not statements. The actual statement (in the sense that this is what the instructor actually meant) is "$\forall x$, If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x>0$". And its negation is "$\exists x$ such that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\le0$". Now it should be clear that the original statement is false and its negation is true. No fuzzy logic or anything weird here!